# Apache restart not working properly?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, lamp, phpmyadmin

I'm newbie to `ubuntu`. And I'll install the [`lamp`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04) and `phpmyadmin` its also working fine, but my problem is when I trying to restart the service of apache2  is not restarting good, its says looks like,

```
   ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ sudo service apache2 restart

   * Restarting web server apache2                                                    [Tue Jul 01 18:59:36.992771 2014] [alias:warn] 
    [pid 23365] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.   
                                                                           [ OK ]
```

Then I try check the `http://localhost` and `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and `phpinfo()` all of them working fine...

I'm trying to fix, And remove the line 3 of following directory `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3`

> Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/"

then apache2 restart is looking good, looks like

> ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
>
> - Restarting web server apache2                 [ OK ]

But, `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` not working its says

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

**`NOTE:`**

1. If I add the Alias (Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/") means phpmyadmin working fine.
2. Next,

> gksu gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

following line add end of the file.

> Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

3. Add, this one also but not working

> Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked to see what the earlier alias was, as referenced by the warning message?

Comment: @saiarcot895, thanks for very first response, and I'm not checking earlier alias

Comment: could you post on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) the content of `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`, `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`?

Comment: @saiarcot895, how can i check alias, like your comment? now if its possible or not?

Comment: Alias directive in the same context are executed in a specific order. For examples if you define `Alias /a /mydir/subdir` and then later in the same context `Alias /a/b /myseconddir/subdir` apache print the warning message because the second Alias will never match. If you don't post your file, is difficult give you help :)

Answer (score 5):

In the file  `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` comment the below line:

`# Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

Then, on  `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`  make sure the following alias is there:

`Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/"`

Restart the apache:

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Now you should be able to use phpmyadmin and the error message should be displayed.

Hope it helps :)